# Не могу понять описание метода differenceBy в документации

Tags: javascript, массивы, lodash

В [документации](https://vaeum.com/2017/03/18/lodash-dokumientatsiia-na-russkom-massivy/#differencebyarrayvaluesiteratee_identity) lodash есть описание метода `differenceBy`

> Этот метод похож на _.difference за исключением того, что он принимает
>   итерацию, которая вызывается для каждого элемента массива и значений
>   для генерации критерия, по которому они сравниваются. Порядок и ссылки
>   на результирующие значения определяются первым массивом. Итератор
>   вызывается с одним аргументом

Не могу понять, что здесь имеется в виду, не могли бы объяснить подробнее?

Comment: Было бы здорово добавить ссылку на то место, откуда вы это взяли - сложно без контекста

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашла, это про `differenceBy` в лодаше. Имеется в виду, что этот метод принимает ещё третий аргумент, функцию, которая будет вызвана на каждый элемент перед их сравнением.

Давайте возьмём пример из документации:

```
_.differenceBy([2.1, 1.2], [2.3, 3.4], Math.floor);
// => [1.2]
```

Функция `Math.floor` будет вызвана на каждый элемент, прежде чем их сравнить. Поэтому 2.1 не попадет в результат, ведь `Math.floor(2.1) === Math.floor(2.3)`

Во втором примере показан короткий способ записи, когда мы работаем с объектами и надо взять значение по ключу. То есть

```
_.differenceBy([{ x: 2 }, { x: 1 }], [{ x: 1 }], 'x')
```

это то же самое, что `_.property('x')` или

```
_.differenceBy([{ x: 2 }, { x: 1 }], [{ x: 1 }], item => item['x'])
```

то есть, мы берём каждый элемент массива и применяем к нему лодашевскую  функцию `property`, которая берёт значение из объекта по указанному пути. Путь - это один или несколько ключей, записанные в виде строки. Как она работает

```
_.property('x')({ x: 2 })
// => 2
```

Соответственно для `{ x: 1 }` из обоих массивов она вернёт `1` и этот элемент будет исключен из результата `differenceBy`

Comment: Для меня просто не понятно что такое генерация критерия, порядок и ссылки путает этот момент. Да и гляньте на второй пример. Третий параметр это уже строка

Comment: @Дима, о каком примере речь? А, все, увидел, там перед этим строчка идет, что это короткая запись для `_.property` - то есть проверяться будет свойство `x`

Comment: @Дима обновила ответ

Comment: @Дима Генерация критерия - это обработка каждого элемента массивов с помощью указанной функции. Если мы не передаём функции, как в обычном `difference`, критериями сравнения являются сами элементы массивов. Если передаём, то критерии генерируются с помощью этой функции

Comment: `item => item['x']` - это слишком упрощенно, потому что в строку передавать можно и `x.y.z` для более глубокого выбора свойства, то есть корректнее указать что то же самое что и `_.property('x')`, о чем и указано в самом примере

Comment: @Grundy пыталась упростить ответ для понимания :) Спасибо, поправила немного ответ

Comment: @Василиса ааааа как-то путаюсь, смотрите, в первом примере передается метод floor, с этим я разобрался каждый элемент массива, допустим 2.4 становится 2 далее сравнивается один массив с другим и создаётся новый отфильтрованный массив с не повторяющимися элементам, во втором примере передаётся строка и получается строку нужно сравнить с один и вторым массивом совпадают ли у них ключи с данном строкой далее отфильтровывать, я так понимаю ?

Comment: @Дима Передаётся не строка, передаётся лодашевская `property` с аргументом, это просто сокращённое написание - опускаем название функции и пишем только сам аргумент. Я ещё раз обновила ответ

Comment: @Василиса, не, передается именно строка, просто внутри это сводится к `return property(value)`: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.4/lodash.js#L6996

Comment: @Василиса У меня такой вопрос, один парень сказал, что если про решать примеры на лодаше самому то буд мега программистом, это так? Стоит ли тратить на это время ? Можете посоветовать что стоит изучать и на что тратить время, направление FRONT

Comment: @Дима это очень спорное заявление, на мой взгляд. Можно стать неплохим знатоком лодаша, но как это связано с мега-программистом? В вашем случае время стоит использовать на изучение основ джаваскрипта, судя по всему, и постепенно продвигаться дальше, в сторону какого-нибудь react/vue/angular. И как можно быстрее искать работу с хорошей командой, которая любит джунов и умеет помогать им учиться. Ничего так не стимулирует к изучению новой технологии, как использование её в твоём рабочем проекте :)

Comment: И да, @Дима, если я ответила на ваш вопрос и вам стало понятнее с `differenceBy`, то мне было бы очень приятно, если бы вы [приняли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) мой ответ

Comment: @Grundy, я понимаю, просто опять пыталась объяснить понятнее, кажется - не вышло :( Спасибо вам за помощь с этим вопросом!

Comment: @Василиса Как понять что стоит переходить допустим на реакт? Читал разные статьи,люди пишут, пока не напишите игру на чистом  JS за фрейворк браться нельзя, Это так ?

Comment: @Дима нет тут какого-то чёткого критерия. Я начала работать на RubyOnRails, не зная толком руби, учила на ходу. Кто-то считает это неправильным - нечего лезть во фреймворк, пока язык не выучил. У меня получилось, всё моё дальнейшее обучение было уже за зарплату :) Так что всё очень индивидуально тут, и у каждого своё мнение. Если вы учитесь, чтобы зарабатывать деньги, то показателем достаточного уровня обучения будет то, что вас взяли на работу. А там дальше уже разберётесь, что учить